# Cocoa SCNetworkInterface getting media sub types

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, networking, osx-yosemite

I'm writing a Cocoa application in Swift that determines the available network interfaces (wifi, ethernet, etc.) and I want to extract the sub type options.

For example, I have a Thunderbolt Ethernet connection and in my Mac's Network Preferences in the Hardware tab I can toggle the speed to be 10baseT/UDP, 100baseTX, etc.

Apple docs say I can use [SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaSubTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaSubTypes) to get an array of available media subtypes (10BaseT/UTP, 100baseTX, etc) and all I need to do is give it a CFArray parameter,

> *available*
>   The available options as returned by the SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions function.

However, the docs specify that [SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCNetworkConfiguration/#//apple_ref/c/func/SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions) returns Bool,

> TRUE if requested information has been returned

I am attempting to use the CFArray of interfaces retrieved with SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll() but SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions(interfaces) returns nil.

```
let interfaces = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyAll()
print(SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaSubTypes(interfaces))

>> nil
```

Here is a screenshot of what I can view in Network preferences

[image]

How can I get this list. Am I using the wrong CFArray? I can't determine what else I can pass in since the suggested SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions returns a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

`SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions` returns a boolean value:

> TRUE if requested information has been returned.

`SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions` returns an array representing the possible media options (subtype, options) in parameter `available`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
    CFArrayRef availableArr;
    CFDictionaryRef currentDict;
    CFDictionaryRef activeDict;
    BOOL one = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaOptions(interface ,&currentDict, &activeDict, &availableArr, NO);
    NSLog(@"availableArr : %@",availableArr);
    NSLog(@"currentDict : %@",currentDict);
    NSLog(@"activeDict : %@",activeDict);


    CFArrayRef MediaSubTypes = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaSubTypes(availableArr);
    NSLog(@"MediaSubTypes : %@",MediaSubTypes);

    NSString *subType = @"autoselect";
    CFArrayRef MediaSubTypeOptions = SCNetworkInterfaceCopyMediaSubTypeOptions(availableArr,(__bridge CFStringRef)subType);
    NSLog(@"MediaSubTypeOptions : %@",MediaSubTypeOptions);
```